# How to pass props from one Component to another component with onClick() event in React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Quick Help Needed! I have Two React components **Vendors** and **VendorsList**. In **Vendors.js** Component i have **asset.asset_name** text rendered in table format. What I want is,  When I click on I **asset.asset_name**, I wanted to pass it's value from **Vendors** component to **VendorsList** component. How could I do this?

Here is code for Two Components

**Vendors.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { axios } from "axios";

const Vendors = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const baseURL =
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/business_process/business-impact/business-assets-detail";

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(baseURL)
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .then(
        (response) => {},
        (err) => {
          alert("No Data To Show");
        }
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        return false;
      });
  }, []);
  const DisplayData = data.business_assets?.map((asset) => {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{asset.business_assets}</td>
        <td onClick={() => alert(asset.asset_name)}>{asset.asset_name}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
  return <div></div>;
};

export default Vendors;
```

Here is **VendorsList.js**

```
    import React from "react";
const VendorsList = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{foo}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VendorsList;
```

I need *asset.asset_name* value to be passed to **VendorsList** when I click on *asset.asset_name* value from **Vendors** component

Comment: Sorry but can you post how you actually pass the `asset_name` into `VendorsList`? Your `Vendors` component doesn't actually render the `DisplayData` nor the `VendorList`. The problem could be a result of you passing the `asset_name` incorrectly to `VendorsList` component

Comment: I did no pass asset_name to VendorsList. I just edited VendorsList.js. Can you see it now? Thanks @ThungPham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're passing the `asset_name` into your `VendorsList` component at all. I think the quickest way is to directly render the `VendorsList` in your `Vendors` component by putting it in the return of your `Vendors` component. You would also need something to record what you have clicked so you can use another `useState` for this. Below is how you'd achieve this:

Modify your `Vendor.js` to look like this:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { axios } from "axios";
import VendorsList from '<path to your VendorList component>'

const Vendors = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [clickedAsset, setClickedAsset] = useState()
  const baseURL =
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/business_process/business-impact/business-assets-detail";

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(baseURL)
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .then(
        (response) => {},
        (err) => {
          alert("No Data To Show");
        }
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        return false;
      });
  }, []);
  const DisplayData = data.business_assets?.map((asset) => {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{asset.business_assets}</td>
        <td onClick={() => setClickedAsset(asset.asset_name)}>{asset.asset_name}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
  return (
      <div>
          <DisplayData/>
          <VendorList clickedAssetName={clickedAsset}/>
      </div>
  );
};

export default Vendors;
```

Then to use the `clickedAssetName` that you just passed, access it like this in your `VendorsList.js` component:

```js
import React from "react";
const VendorsList = ({clickedAssetName}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{clickedAssetName}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VendorsList;
```

Comment: I got **undefined** from **VendorsList** when I run this code. could you help me please? @TungPham

Comment: @TeshieEthiopia Sorry, did not see that you've replied, are you getting undefined after the click or is it just display undefined at first? You have to click the button to actually have the value set correctly.

Comment: can how can I pass this using redux? because it's impossible to pass useState value directly to another component. Can you show me how this can be implemented using redux? Thanks

Comment: @TeshieEthiopia So if you want to use redux, you can use the `useSelector` [hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) to get the value, and `useDispatch` to dispatch the action to modify the redux state. This, IMO, outside the scope of your original question so I'd recommend you look at the docs, try it yourself and you can post another question here if you stuck so people can help out.